# Prove: If u, v, w are integers such that $u^2 + v^2 = w^2$ , then $u$ and $v$ can’t be both odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve this problem, But I'm unable to get a single hint
can you help me to solve this problem.

> If $u$, $v$, $w$ are integers such that $u^2 + v^2 = w^2$ , then $u$ and $v$ can’t
>   be both odd.

Comment: Hint: Try working modulo $4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that $w^2 \equiv 0,1 \mod4$

Now try to calculate $u^2+v^2 \mod 4$ if $u$, $v$ are odds

Comment: I'm unable to get this one, can you explain it?

Comment: If $w$ is odd then $w=2n+1$ for some $n$ then $w^2=4n^2+4n+1$. If $w$ is even then $w=2n$ form some $n$ then $w^2=4n^2$

Answer (score 0):

A direct (contradictory) proof:

Let $u$ and $v$ odd and set  $u=2m+1$ and $v=2n+1$. Then you have
$$
u^2 + v^2 = 4 (m^2 + n^2 + n+m) +2
$$

Now this is even, so $w^2$ is even, so  $w$ had to be even and you can set $w = 2k$ . So you need

$$
4k^2  =  4 (m^2 + n^2 + n+m) +2
$$

or

$$
k^2 -( m^2 + n^2 + n+m) =  \frac12
$$

Now this is a contradiction since all terms are integer and hence the LHS can never give $\frac12$.